# Double Eclipse Icon

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a little problem when i'm installing eclipse on my elementaryOS. In fact, this problem persists when i'm using ubuntu gnome or unity.

I have eclipse on my home folder, and I create a eclipse.desktop. The icon looks good, but when I open eclipse, another blurry icon appears (Its name is "Java - Eclipse") apart of the normal icon.

I want have only the normal icon. I read about some similar troubles with the google chrome icon but the threads can't help me.

Can anyone helps me?

Thanks in advance.

My desktop entry is on /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop

Comment: share your screen shot here http://imgur.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal behavior for eclipse.exe. The icon you have on your desktop is the eclipse launcher, which is not the same as the actual eclipse IDE.

You can read more about how and why [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Flauncher.html).